# Projection of a covering map over product set.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $p,q$ be a covering maps, $p:\tilde X \rightarrow X$ and $q:\tilde Y \rightarrow X$ and let $Z=\lbrace(\tilde x, \tilde y)| p(\tilde x)=q(\tilde y) \rbrace$, I want to prove that $f:\tilde Z\rightarrow X$ definided by
$f(\tilde x, \tilde y)=p(\tilde x)$ is a covering map too, I try putting for any $x$ in $X$ the same
open set $U_x$ given by the covering map $p$ and applying the properties of this open set $U_x$ in $f$, by
inverse image of $f$, but at the and this don´t work, some help to prove this is well.
Thanks.

Comment: Is $X=Y$? Otherwise the expression $p(\tilde{x})=q(\tilde{y})$ does not make sense.

Comment: If $X=Y$ it is even enough to assume that only one of the two maps is a covering. $Z$ is the so-called pullback of those maps and pullbacks of covering spaces are covering spaces as asked in the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494024/pullback-of-a-covering-map

Comment: In that case, your question is answered by my second comment.